# Parse conf file Java

Tags: java, file, parsing

Can you tell me best way to parse a file like this:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# prices
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Au333    237.41
Au375    267.35
Au500    356.47
```

/# - its comment

Au333=237.41 (like key=value). But in my file no '=', instead just some space.
I want something like class Properties in Java. But this class works when you have '=' between key and value

Comment: You write your own class, I guess. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I just thought that there is a solution. If no, I'll write a parser itself.

Comment: I believe load(InputStream is) method already has a support for this. Can you please try loading properties using above property file

Comment: Im stupid, really Properties works with my file. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace is a key terminator in Java [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) files, so what you have should work.

#### data.properties

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# prices
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Au333    237.41
Au375    267.35
Au500    356.47
```

#### PropsLoaderExample.java

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("resources/data.properties");
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("Au333"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("Au375"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("Au500"));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note:** Don't swallow exceptions like that. This is just to test with.

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems to me is a special case of CSV file. You can use [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse it.

```
  CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), "  ");
     String [] nextLine;
     while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read each line and create a method to extract the two data points.
something like

```
public static void parseLine(String line)
{
    StrArr.add(line.substring(0,5));
    line = line.substring(5,line.length);
    IntArr.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an esay way to acomplish the task:

```
String keyAndValue = "Au333    237.41";
String[] keyAndValueArray = keyAndValue.split(" ");
String key = keyAndValue.split(" ")[0];
String value = keyAndValue.split(" ")[keyAndValueArray.length - 1];
```

Hope it helps!